# Restart ipython kernel started via 'ipython kernel'

Tags: python, ipython

I have an ipython kernel started via

```
ipython kernel
```

This gives me the option to connect to this kernel from different clients (console, qtconsole or even from other machine via ssh.

The simplest case is to connect locally via:

```
ipython qtconsole --existing kernel-xxxx.json
```

But if I now want to restart the kernel (usually via `Ctrl+.` in qtconsole), I get the message:

```
Cannot restart a Kernel I did not start
```

This is logical, but my **question** is:

- Is there a way to restart an IPython kernel via a connected client?

Or, if this is not possible:

- Is there a way to trigger the restart of the kernel via some other command? (from the local console, not the connected client).

I'm not looking for a way to quit the `ipython kernel` process (can be done via `Ctrl+\`), but just to restart the kernel without changing the kernel id.

---

*Some info about my (I)Python environment:*

```
python -c "import IPython; print(IPython.sys_info())"

{'commit_hash': u'2d95975',
'commit_source': 'repository',
'default_encoding': 'UTF-8',
'ipython_path': '/something/gits/ipython/IPython',
'ipython_version': '3.2.1',
'os_name': 'posix',
'platform': 'Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-8.0',
'sys_executable': '/usr/bin/python',
'sys_platform': 'linux2',
'sys_version': '2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that at present. It's a limitation we plan to remove at some point.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this clarification. Do you know if there is a github issue on this topic? I did not find anything special, but maybe you have a better overview if you are aware of this limitation.

Comment: It's touched on in [IPEP 12](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-12%3A-Splitting-KernelManager-and-KernelClient).

Comment: Thanks. I think if you combine both comments into an answer I could accept it, as it clearly answers my question and others might stumble upon the same thing when they try the `ipython kernel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to restart a kernel from a frontend that didn't start it. That's a limitation we plan to remove at some point - [IPEP 12](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-12%3A-Splitting-KernelManager-and-KernelClient) touches on those plans.

Comment: How this going?